# Generic container assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, template

For setters that set a member collection, I write template functions so as to accept any collection type as input:

```
class HasItems
{
public:
    template <typename C>
    void items(const C& items) {
        // Copy-and-swap omitted
        m_items.assign(std::begin(items), std::end(items));
    }

private:
    std::vector<Item> m_items;
}
```

But suppose `Item` is big, and I want to move them around instead of copy if possible.  And furthermore, suppose someone passed me an xvalue `std::vector<Item>`; I could just move that whole container into place and avoid touching the elements at all!  That looks like this:

```
class HasItems
{
public:
    template <typename C>
    void items(C&& items) {
        // Helper function implemented below
        assign(m_items, std::forward<C>(items));
    }

private:
    std::vector<Item> m_items;
}

// Assigns the contents of src to dest, moving as much as possible
template <typename C1, typename C2>
void assign(C1& dest, C2&& src) {
    assign(dest, std::forward<C2>(src), std::is_assignable<C1&, C2&&>{});
}

// Called if we can use operator=
template <typename C1, typename C2>
void assign(C1& dest, C2&& src, std::true_type use_equals) {
    dest = std::forward<C2>(src);
}

// Called if we must use dest.assign()
template <typename C1, typename C2>
void assign(C1& dest, C2&& src, std::false_type use_equals) {
    assign_elements(dest, std::forward<C2>(src), std::is_rvalue_reference<C2&&>{});
}

// Called if we can move the elements
template <typename C1, typename C2>
void assign_elements(C1& dest, C2&& src, std::true_type move) {
    dest.assign(std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(src)),
                std::make_move_iterator(std::end(src)));
}

// Called if we must copy the elements
template <typename C1, typename C2>
void assign_elements(C1& dest, C2&& src, std::false_type move) {
    dest.assign(std::begin(src), std::end(src));
}
```

Is this a good approach?  In particular, is there a nice way to avoid the tag dispatch on `std::is_rvalue_reference<C2&&>` in the `assign_elements()` case?  (It was avoided in the `operator=` case by using `dest = std::forward<C2>(src)` instead of using `std::move()` conditionally.)  It seems to pass my simple set of unit tests.

Answer (score 4):

I've implemented this idiom and discovered a major caveat after a few weeks: it doesn't play nicely with [`boost::iterator_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html) or other collection views.  An example:

```
std::vector<std::string> dest;
std::list<std::string> src{"foo", "bar"};
// Moves elements out of src, expected
assign(dest, std::move(src));

src = {"foo", "bar"};
// Also moves elements out of src!!!
assign(dest, boost::make_iterator_range(src));
```

This happens because `boost::make_iterator_range(src)` is an xvalue.  I don't see a good way to distinguish between "container" (meaning safe to move from xvalues) and "container view" (meaning not safe to move from).

Comment: You should ask that on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). My guess is you need `assign` to take iterators instead and do the right thing depending on if they are move iterators.